# How would I filter ggplot to display the top 15 values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I would like to filter the ggplot by the top 15 values of `start_station_name`.

This is my code:

```
ggplot(trips_data2) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x=start_station_name, fill=member_casual), 
           position = "dodge", width = .7) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) + 
  labs(x="Station", y="Total Trips", fill = "Member") + 
  ggtitle("Popular Start Stations") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

This is a sample from my data using `dput(head(trips_data2))`:

```
trips_data2 <- structure(list(ride_id = c(
  "A847FADBBC638E45", "5405B80E996FF60D",
  "5DD24A79A4E006F4", "2A59BBDF5CDBA725", "27AD306C119C6158", "356216E875132F61"
), rideable_type = c(
  "docked_bike", "docked_bike", "docked_bike",
  "docked_bike", "docked_bike", "docked_bike"
), started_at = structure(c(
  1587923100,
  1587143280, 1585763640, 1586263800, 1587205320, 1588269300
), class = c(
  "POSIXct",
  "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), ended_at = structure(c(
  1587924720,
  1587143820, 1585764480, 1586264520, 1587208500, 1588269660
), class = c(
  "POSIXct",
  "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), start_station_name = c(
  "Eckhart Park",
  "Drake Ave & Fullerton Ave", "McClurg Ct & Erie St", "California Ave & Division St",
  "Rush St & Hubbard St", "Mies van der Rohe Way & Chicago Ave"
), start_station_id = c("86", "503", "142", "216", "125", "173"), end_station_name = c(
  "Lincoln Ave & Diversey Pkwy", "Kosciuszko Park",
  "Indiana Ave & Roosevelt Rd", "Wood St & Augusta Blvd", "Sheridan Rd & Lawrence Ave",
  "Streeter Dr & Grand Ave"
), end_station_id = c(
  "152", "499",
  "255", "657", "323", "35"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: How about `trips_data2 %>% arrange(desc(start_station_name)) %>% slice_head(n=15) %>% ggplot() + ...`.  This should work if what you mean by "top" are the highest values.  If what you mean by top are the ones that are already at the top of the data frame, you can omit the `arrange()` step.

Comment: Just filter your data frame before calling `ggplot`.

Comment: Didn't work, it just displayed what was in row 15.

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
library(tidyverse)

trips_data2 %>% 
  mutate(start_station_name = fct_lump(start_station_name, n = 15)) %>% 
  count(start_station_name) %>% 
  mutate(start_station_name = fct_reorder(start_station_name, n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=start_station_name, y=n, fill=member_casual))) +
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x="Station", y="Total Trips", fill = "Member") + 
  ggtitle("Popular Start Stations") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:   Error in count(., start_station_name) : 
object 'start_station_name' not found

Comment: Have you loaded `library(tidyverse)` if yes, then replace `count` with `dplyr::count`

Comment: Same error and tidyverse is loaded

Comment: ok removed pipe. If you could provide some data. I would like to show you the concept of `fct_lump` which is really handy in this situation. Otherwise it is always a guess.  :-(

Comment: hmm yes, which data?

Comment: Write in your console `dput(trips_data2)`. Then copy the output and put it to your question via edit at the bottom of your question.